# Loop over Vector in R for n times and plot graphs in a grid

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to loop my for loop below for the values in the vector as follows.

```
Vector = nsize<-c(5,10,30,150)
```

For Loop :

```
store<-numeric()
for (i in 1:5000){
z<- rexp(nsize,5)
store[i]<-mean(z)
}
hist(store)
}
```

Can someone please let let me know how do i pass all the values in my vector to the for loop and plot the graphs side by side.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Anilaaryan, welcome to SO.
Please add relevant tags to the question for others to find it easily and help answer.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. `rexp()` will consecutively return a vector of 5 values, 10 values, 30 values, and 150 values. What is the purpose of `1:5000`?